# Determine if string is encoded HTML via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html-encode

I'm working on a validation script, but I'm running into a very particular issue.

If a user enters a string that happens to be an encoded html character (like `&#38;` or `&amp;`), it will output as the character (& in this case). My question is this: is it possible to write a function that detemines if a string is an encoded character? So if the user enters one of the two above options, I want to launch a particular function, and if it's a non-encoded character, I want to do something else.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to test just for those two specific examples, or for _any_ html character entities? If it's just those two a simple regex should do it: `if (/&#38;|&amp;/.test(strVar)) { ... }`

Comment: @streetlight- you can onkeypress() and check for ( &#38; or &amp;) It will run goood.!

Comment: I'm am trying to do all html character entries, not just these specific two. Thank you though!

Answer (score 3):

By definition, if you do not know whether something is an encoded HTML entity or not you do not know. Either you treat all text coming from a certain source as encoded or not encoded. Why? Because it's all just text. "&amp;" is just text. I *meant* to write "&amp;" here. I do not want anyone to interpret it, I want it to appear literally as "&amp;".

How do you know what the user meant? If you're starting to replace user-entered text based on guesses, you'll always screw it up in some cases. It's the typical case where all ":D" is replaced by a graphical smilie, which is annoying when you actually wanted to type ":D".

If you want to always preserve exactly what the user entered, always run all user input through an HTML-encoding function which replaces all special characters with entities. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a string contains encoded characters by comparing the encoded vs decoded lengths:

```
var string = "Your encoded &amp; decoded string here"

function decode(str){
    return decodeURIComponent(str).replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
}

if(string.length == decode(string).length){
    // The string does not contain any encoded html.
}else{
    // The string contains encoded html.
}
```

Also, this is [significantly faster than the jQuery method that was suggested.](http://jsperf.com/check-if-string-contains-encoded-html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it.

```
function containsEncoded (val){
    var rHTMLEncoded = /&[^\s]*/;

    return rHTMLEncoded.test(val) ;
}


// Usage 
var encoded = containsEncoded("&amp;");
```