# How to handle possibly HTML encoded values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding, decoding

I have a situation where I'm not sure if the input I get is HTML encoded or not. How do I handle this? I also have jQuery available.

```
function someFunction(userInput){
    $someJqueryElement.text(userInput);
}

// userInput "<script>" returns "&lt;script&gt;", which is fine
// userInput "&lt;script&gt;" returns &amp;lt;script&amp;gt;", which is bad
```

I could avoid escaping ampersands (`&`), but what are the risks in that? Any help is very much appreciated!

**Important note:**  This user input is not in my control. It returns from a external service, and it is possible for someone to tamper with it and avoid the html escaping provided by that service itself.

Comment: You _really_ need to avoid those situations.  Why aren't you sure?

Comment: Why does it matter if the input is already encoded? If the user enters the literal `&lt;script&gt;`, then that is what should be displayed. Encoding it won't change how it renders.

Comment: _I have a situation where I'm not sure if the input I get is HTML encoded or not_ -- this is bad.

Comment: @SLaks you are very right, however this input is not in my control. It returns from a external service, and it is possible for someone to tamper with it and avoid the html escaping they do.

Comment: @Justus if you had put that in your original post, you wouldn't have 4 useless comments now ;)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I will update the question :) good point

Comment: If you can't control the external service, then always HTML encode everything. If the result is doubly-encoded, direct complaints to the external service. Really, the situation sounds like an unwinnable mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to make sure you avoid these situations as it introduces really difficult conditions to predict.

Try adding an additional variable input to the function.

```
function someFunction(userInput, isEncoded){
    //Add some conditional logic based on isEncoded
    $someJqueryElement.text(userInput);
}
```

If you look at products like fckEditor, you can choose to edit source or use the rich text editor. This prevents the need for automatic encoding detection.

If you are still insistent on automatically detecting html encoding characters, I would recommend using index of to verify that certain key phrases exist.

```
str.indexOf('&lt;') !== -1
```

This example above will detect the < character.

**~~~New text added after edit below this line.~~~**

Finally, I would suggest looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703479/516561). They suggest using the decode function and detecting lengths.

```
var string = "Your encoded &amp; decoded string here"

function decode(str){
    return decodeURIComponent(str).replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
}

if(string.length == decode(string).length){
    // The string does not contain any encoded html.
}else{
    // The string contains encoded html.
}
```

Again, this still has the problem of a user faking out the process by entering those specially encoded characters, but that is what html encoding is. So it would be proper to assume html encoding as soon as one of these character sequences comes up.

Comment: I like your practical solution, but it is also very easy to let the input pass by just adding this `&lt;` string somewhere in the input.

Comment: Thanks for the link, great explanation there why I'm screwed with not knowing if escaping is done or not.

Comment: That code is very wrong.  URI escaping has nothing to do with HTML escaping, and that doesn't properly cover HTML escaping.

Comment: SLaks, He is not asking to for anything with a URL. There is nothing wrong with the code other than the fact that it is probably a very bad to detect this way. 

Of course it does not properly cover, which is why the text of the answer says it is not a great idea. The OP asked for the code, not for the moral justification for writing code that way.

Answer (score 1):

You must **always** correctly encode untrusted input before concatenating it into a structured language like HTML.

Otherwise, you'll enable injection attacks like XSS.

If the input is supposed to contain HTML formatting, you should use a sanitizer library to strip all potentially unsafe tags & attributes.

You can also use the regex `/<|>|&(?![a-z]+;)` to check whether a string has any non-encoded characters; however, you cannot distinguish a string that has been encoded from an unencoded string that talks about encoding.

Comment: I totally agree, however is there a way to check if it is encoded or not, or to avoid those ugly double-encoded messages?

Comment: @JustusRomijn: `if (!/<|>|&(?![a-z]+;)/.test(source))`.  However, you cannot tell whether text like `&lt;` is supposed to be an encoded `<` or whether it's supposed to be literal text talking about XML.

Comment: Nice regex, maybe you want to add it to your answer? I think I could get somewhere with that.